# mysql select columns and sum from other table

Tags: mysql, select, join, sum

I have the following tables:

```
A: id, name, url
B: Aid, number
```

number can be any int
(Aid is the id from table A)

I want to select the name, url from table A and the SUM(B.number) 
So the results will be something like:

```
name, url, SUM(B.number)
name, url, SUM(B.number)
name, url, SUM(B.number)
[..]
```

I need to join them somehow? How do i construct that query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT name, url, (SELECT SUM(number) FROM B WHERE B.Aid = A.id) As total
FROM A
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT A.name, A.url, SUM(B.number) 
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.Aid 
GROUP BY A.name, A.url
```

Please test it before cause I might have made a mistake since I got no MySQL DB available at the moment.